# How to get the summary of items in a List using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

```
Public Class Product
public  Name As String
public  ID as String
public  ShelfList as List(of Shelf)
End Class 

Public Class Shelf
public  Name As String
public  ID as String
public  Row as List(of Row)
End Class

Public Class Row
public  Name As String
public  ID as String
End Class
```

The above are my classes.
Suppose a product can be found in different shelf and different rows.
Also a row can accommodate multiple product.

Data will be similar to this.

```
List(of Products) -> List(of Shelf) -> List(of Rows)
```

Following is the similar data

```
Boost ->  Shelf 1 -> Row 1,Row 2 
          Shelf 2 -> Row 2

Horlicks ->Shelf 1-> Row 1

Complain ->Shelf 2-> Row 2,Row 3

Colgate -> Shelf 2- Row 3
```

So from the above list of products I need to generate the summary. (Row name and number of items in each row)

```
   Shelf 1 Row 1 - 2 (Boost and horlicks)
   Shelf 1 Row 2 - 1 (Boost)
   Shelf 2 Row 1 - 1 (Horlicks)
   Shelf 2 Row 2 - 2 (Complain and Boost)
   Shelf 2 Row 3 - 1 (Colgate)
```

Note :

1. Shelf 1 Row 1 is the name of the first row of first shelf.
2. No need for displaying the item names in bracket. Now just showing for understanding.

How to achieve this using LINQ. 
I am using VB.NET and targeting CE 3.5. C# suggestion also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your data structure

I would do it like this

List of Shelf  --> List of Row  --> List of Product

Why would a Product track the row?
It is the row which contains the different products.

For Each Shelf

Select Shelf number --> Row Number -- > Product name

Comment: But As per the design, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest LINQ queries,  for example (sorry, I'm a C-sharp man);

```
var a = from t1 in Products
        select new 
        {
             Name = t1.Name,
             Summary = String.Join(", ",(from t2 in t1.ShelfList
                        select t2.Name))
        };
```

Something like that ought to do,  although I'm ignoring the third tier.